# Convert delimited string to numeric vector in dataframe

Tags: r

This is such a basic question, I'm embarrassed to ask.

Let's say I have a dataframe full of columns which contain data of the following form:

```
test <-"3000,9843,9291,2161,3458,2347,22925,55836,2890,2824,2848,2805,2808,2775,2760,2706,2727,2688,2727,2658,2654,2588"
```

I want to convert this to a numeric vector, which I have done like so:

```
test <- as.numeric(unlist(strsplit(test, split=",")))
```

I now want to convert a large dataframe containing a column full of this data into a numeric vector equivalent:

```
mutate(data,
  converted = as.numeric(unlist(strsplit(badColumn, split=","))),
)
```

This doesn't work because presumably it's converting the entire column into a numeric vector and then replacing a single row with that value:

> Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) :    Column `converted` must be
>   length 20 (the number of rows) or one, not 1274

How do I do this?

Comment: The column is too long after you split it. It looks like your data only have 20 rows, but the split column has 1274 elements. If you don't want to assign it as a new column in the data (which is what mutate does), you can do `as.numeric(unlist(strsplit(data$badColumn, split=",")))`

Comment: I understand, but I'm confused as to why that's the case.  The current rows contain values like "10, 20, 30, 40" I just want those values to be replaced with a numeric vector equivalent c(10, 20, 30, 40).

Comment: So you want multiple numeric values in a given row? E.g. row 1 might have `c(10,20,30)`?

Comment: Correct.  I think I can wrap data.frame around the as.numeric, but I don't want it to be a dataframe within a dataframe, I want it to be a numeric vector.  But I could also just be talking nonsense

Comment: ^^ This is actually the best answer.  Post as solution please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's some sample data that reproduces your error:

```
data <- data.frame(a = 1:3, 
                   badColumn = c("10,20,30,40,50", "1,2,3,4,5,6", "9,8,7,6,5,4,3"), 
                   stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Here's the error:

```
library(tidyverse)
mutate(data, converted = as.numeric(unlist(strsplit(badColumn, split=","))))
# Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
#   Column `converted` must be length 3 (the number of rows) or one, not 18
```

A straightforward way would be to just use `strsplit` on the entire column, and `lapply` ... `as.numeric` to convert the resulting list values from character vectors to numeric vectors.

```
x <- mutate(data, converted = lapply(strsplit(badColumn, ",", TRUE), as.numeric))
str(x)
# 'data.frame': 3 obs. of  3 variables:
#  $ a        : int  1 2 3
#  $ badColumn: chr  "10,20,30,40,50" "1,2,3,4,5,6" "9,8,7,6,5,4,3"
#  $ converted:List of 3
#   ..$ : num  10 20 30 40 50
#   ..$ : num  1 2 3 4 5 6
#   ..$ : num  9 8 7 6 5 4 3
```

Answer (score 2):

This might help:

```
library(purrr)

mutate(data, converted = map(badColumn, function(txt) as.numeric(unlist(strsplit(txt, split = ",")))))
```

What you get is a list column which contains the numeric vectors.

Comment: This is a good answer -- thanks kath.  I 'm accepting A5s answer as it strikes me as a bit clearer

Answer (score 1):

Base R

```
A=c(as.numeric(strsplit(test,',')[[1]]))

A
[1]  3000  9843  9291  2161  3458  2347 22925 55836  2890  2824  2848  2805  2808  2775  2760  2706  2727  2688  2727  2658  2654  2588


df$NEw2=lapply(df$NEw, function(x) c(as.numeric(strsplit(x,',')[[1]])))

df%>%mutate(NEw2=list(c(as.numeric(strsplit(NEw,',')[[1]]))))
```

Comment: This just replicates the function I already had above.  My problem is physically replacing the column in the dataframe (which currently contains the strings) with the numeric vector equivalent